# Unable to mount /data after multiple wiped

Tags: rooting, twrp, file-system, partitions, samsung-galaxy-j5

Everytime I try to flash anything from TWRP it says "E: unable to mount /data". I have tried multiple wipes and entirely reflashing the os but everytime i finish setting up the phone after wiping it, it goes back to that error.

Phone is a Samsung J5 Prime (G570Y)

Answer (score 0):

How did you reflash the OS? using TWRP or ODIN?

A simpler solution is to flash Stock Firmware for your device via ODIN & then flash TWRP again.

You might first want to try the solution suggested on this XDA Thread if you are comfortable with using Terminal 
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2683787

Reflashing the Stock Firmware via ODIN will most likely fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i found a solution a few minutes after i posted this question.

The solution is to

- download the stock firmware
- then open up the AP Tar and
  replace the boot.img and recovery.img with the patched kernel and
  twrp respectively.
- then flash the AP Along with the BL, CL AND CSC
  files you get with the stock firmware file.